# Proving $\{9^n|n\in \mathbb Q\} = \{3^n|n\in \mathbb Q\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The statement is: $\{9^n|n\in \mathbb Q\} = \{3^n|n\in \mathbb Q\}$.

I am more familiar with traditional proofs. Do I just split up $9^n$ into $3^{n}\times 3^{n}$?

Comment: To show that your statement holds you need to simply show that each set is a subset of the other. Can you show that one is a subset of the other?

Comment: So starting with $9^n \subset 3^n$?

Comment: Yeah show that if $a\in \{9^n | n\in Q \}$ then $a\in \{3^n | n\in Q\}$. Then similarly show the other direction.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that for any $\;n\in\Bbb Q\;$

$$\begin{cases}9^n=3^{2n}\\{}\\3^{n}=9^{n/2}\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies\left\{\,9^n\;:\;n\in\Bbb Q\right\}=\left\{\,3^n\;:\;n\in\Bbb Q\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose $x \in \{9^n\:|\:n \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Then there exists $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $x = 9^a$. So, $x = 9^a = 3^{2a}$ and $3^{2a} \in \{3^n\:|\:n \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Hence, $\{9^n\:|\:n \in \mathbb{Q}\} \subseteq\{3^n\:|\:n \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Try to show the opposite inclusion.

Comment: Almost the reverse. Having $3^n$ - then there is a $n \in Q$ where $n=2a$. Then go from there? @user35603

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$=$\{9^n|n\in Q\}$ and $A= \{3^n|n\in Q\}$.
Let $x \in A$ $\implies$ $x$=$3^n$ $\implies$ $x$=$ 9^ \frac{n} {2}$ and n $\in$ $Q$ $\implies$ $\frac {n}{2}$ $\in Q$ $i.e. x \in B$ So $A\subset B$. 
Again if $y \in B$ $\implies$ $y$=$9^m$ $\implies$ $y$=$ 3^{2m}$ and $m$ $\in$ $Q$ $\implies$ $2m $ $\in Q$ $i.e. y\in A$ so $B\subset A$. Hence we can say $A=B$.